# Why is communism hated by some ppl?

Tags: communism, capitalism

Communists ideologies are against Capitalism and Privatization...Well it seemed a good thought in Marx's era...he was fighting against the "gap" what so called a "class" b/w rich and poor sections of the society.

So if these ideas are good and seems to be good...then why communism is evil to sm ppl??

PS: Correct me if I'm wrong in my question.

Comment: I fear that your question is not suitable for this kind of forum. The question gets into value judgements of freedom, justice, and fairness, and how they should be balanced in an economy.

Comment: Agree, more of a political/philosophical question.  But for a simple answer, suppose you're one of the "haves" (even if only modestly so), and people suggest taking away what you have to benefit others.  Would you like those people?

Comment: Because I like and prefer capitalism and privatization, and I dislike anything that undercuts those values? Because I think that taking away from one person to give to another is morally suspect?  Because the group making the decision to take away always profits?  Because calling extortion and robbery by multi-syllable names doesn't make them right? Because I don't believe in the existence of the proletariat? Because I don't like theocracies?

Answer (score 6):

I will try to answer mostly PS. This question is wrong because you address only the "theory" of communism. That is what communists writers write. These ideas indeed had attracted many people in the past, and even attract some nowadays.

However the hatred of communism is mostly based on its PRACTICE, not on the theory. Communist regimes, ALL of them, without exception, mean deprivation of people of freedom, and mass murders on the scale not comparable with any other ideology. Read the history of Soviet Union, China, Cambodia, Eastern European communist regimes, Korea, Vietnam and so on. If you want a condensed exposition, read the book "Black Book of Communism". The authors just collected the facts.

Of course one can ask why is there an apparent discrepancy between communist theory and communist practice. Well, whenever such discrepancy appears one should conclude that the theory is wrong.

There is one country by the way where people can choose to live in a communist society freely. And come back to the normal society if they wish. This is Israel.
About 100000 of Israelis 1.2% of poulation, live in 270 communes called kibuzzim. They are organized on the principles of communist society, more or less.
No one has a slightest objection to this.

But when communists begin to ENFORCE their ideas on the rest of population, this always leads to mass murders, starvation and other similar consequences.

Comment: +1 for a great answer to a vague question

Comment: People can also choose to live in a communist society in the US, and many other countries.  See for instance the "hippie" communes of the 1960s and '70s, some of which have survived, e.g. http://abcnews.go.com/Business/oldest-hippie-commune-alive/story?id=17836147

Comment: @jamesqf: That's correct. But Israeli communities are most famous, and exist for long time.

Comment: Please note that all such successful "communist" communities have members in the few hundreds at most. If something works in a small community, it doesn't mean it will work for a whole country. Especially if that small community is formed by like-minded people going there voluntarily.